# Contacts disappear at join from database

Tags: php, database, laravel

This is my first code, which works perfect and shows me three contacts.

```
$data['contact_users'] = DB::table('contacts')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.contact_id')
                ->join('industries', 'industries.id', '=', 'users.industry_id')
                ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
                ->join('organization_types', 'organization_types.id', '=', 'users.organization_type_id')
                ->join("role_users", "role_users.user_id","=","users.id")
                ->select('users.*', 'industries.industry', 'countries.country', 'organization_types.organization_type', "role_users.role_id")
                ->where('contacts.contact_id', '!=', $id)
                ->where('users.deleted_at', '=', null)
                ->whereIn('contacts.user_id', $contact_id)
                ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $contact_id)
                ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $inviter_id)
                ->groupBy('contact_id')
                ->take(4)
                ->get();
```

Now,I am trying to get some data from database( I need function name) but now I have only one contact, with `career_path(function)` and I need all my contacts, I don't know why two contacts just disappear.
Here is my updated code with import of `career_paths`:

```
$data['contact_users'] = DB::table('contacts')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.contact_id')
                ->join('industries', 'industries.id', '=', 'users.industry_id')
                ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
                ->join('organization_types', 'organization_types.id', '=', 'users.organization_type_id')
                ->join("role_users", "role_users.user_id","=","users.id")
                ->join("career_paths", "career_paths.user_id","=","users.id")
                ->select('users.*', 'industries.industry', 'countries.country', 'organization_types.organization_type', "role_users.role_id", "career_paths.function_id")
                ->where('contacts.contact_id', '!=', $id)
                ->where('users.deleted_at', '=', null)
                ->whereIn('contacts.user_id', $contact_id)
                ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $contact_id)
                ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $inviter_id)
                ->groupBy('contact_id')
                ->take(4)
                ->get();
```

My database structure is like this:
`career_paths->id & user_id & industry_id & department_id & function_id`
`functions->function`.

I will use `function_id` in my view like this : 
`{{$contact->function_id}}`

Comment: Possibly because `->join` performs an `INNER JOIN` so if there's no data on one of those joined tables, it'll drop the row ... try `->leftJoin`

Comment: thank you so much...Only a word can change the entire code:)